# Why can I compile a code with 2 returns?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, compiler-warnings, unreachable-code

Since am comming from a java island, I wounder why the compiler doesnt warns about unreachable code in something like:

```
int main(int argc, char** argV)
{

    std::list<int> lst = {1,2,3,4};

    return 0;



    std::cout << "Done!!!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

my question:

Why can I compile a code with 2 returns?

my Compiler is gcc for c++11, on Windows, code block

Comment: Can you think of a reason why you shouldn't be able to ?

Comment: `why the compiler doesnt warns` And your warning level setting is...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I wounder why the compiler doesnt warns about unreachable code in something like

It is pretty well explained in gcc [documentaion](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/gcc/Warning-Options.html) about warnings:

> -Wunreachable-code
>
> Warn if the compiler detects that code will never be executed. This option is intended to warn when the compiler detects
> that at least a whole line of source code will never be executed,
> because some condition is never satisfied or because it is after a
> procedure that never returns.
>
> It is possible for this option to produce a warning even though there
> are circumstances under which part of the affected line can be
> executed, so care should be taken when removing apparently-unreachable
> code.
>
> For instance, when a function is inlined, a warning may mean that the
> line is unreachable in only one inlined copy of the function.
>
> **This option is not made part of -Wall because in a debugging version
> of a program there is often substantial code which checks correct
> functioning of the program and is, hopefully, unreachable because the
> program does work. Another common use of unreachable code is to
> provide behavior which is selectable at compile-time.**

Though g++ 5.1.0 does not produce any warnings for this code even with this option enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Why shouldn't you be able to compile code that has multiple returns?
Because the code is unreachable? Most compilers can issue a warning for that.

However, I often see code like:

```
   if(a)
   {
      // Do stuff
   }
   else
   {
      // Do other stuff

      if(b)
      {
          // Do more stuff
      }
      else
      {
          // Do other more stuff
      }
   }
```

That could be simplified as

```
   if(a)
   {
      // Do stuff
      return;
   }

   // Do other stuff

   if(b)
   {
      // Do more stuff
      return;
   }

   // Do other more stuff
```

About a decade ago, people frowned on having more than one return in a function of method, but there really is no reason to continue frowning on it with modern compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Because this part

```
std::cout << "Done!!!" << std::endl;
return 0;
```

will never be called because of the first `return` statement, but it is not an error aborting the compilation, rather the compiler might drop a warning, depending on what compiler you are using (e.g. Microsofts VC++ compiler warns you about that).

Answer (score 0):

Mainly because more often than not the compiler cannot know for sure. (There have been attempts to do this in Java but there the criteria for defining *reachability* have been decided upon.)

In this case, indeed, it is obvious.

Some compilers do issue reachability warnings but the C++ standard does not require this.

No answer on reachability is complete without referencing this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

As a final remark on Java, consider these two Java snippets:

```
if (true){
    return;
}
; // this statement is defined to be reachable
```

and

```
while (true){
    return;
}
; // this statement is defined to be unreachable
```

The worst of both worlds is attained, in my humble opinion.

Comment: Related: Java warns *too often*, because like said 100% correctness is impossible. Not just for reachability things, but also for things like code paths without initialization etc.

Answer (score 0):

Unreachable code is not a compile error in C++, but usually gives a warning, depending on your compiler and flags.

You can try to add -Wall option when you call your compiler. This will
active many useful warning.

Comment: - wall is checked!

Comment: it needs -Wunreachable-code wich is not included into -Wall

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons for this:

1. C++ has many standards (c++11, c++14, c++17 etc. ) unlike java (java is very rigid in standard and only thing that matters really with java is the version you are using), so, some compilers might warn you about the unreachable code while others might not.
2. The statements after `return 0`, though are unreachable logically, do not cause any fatal error like ambiguity, syntax error, etc. and can be compiled easily (if the compiler wills to ;) ).

Comment: `C++ has many standards (c++11, c++14, c++17 etc. ) unlike java` Not unlike Java. The language Java has versions too, and that's not equal to the software version.